# How do I make the input read and display my image?

Tags: javascript

```
    <input type="text" name="upload-url" id="url-input" style="width: 250px;" placeholder="http://example.com/image.png">
        <input onclick="show()" value="Add picture">
    <p id="image"></p>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="upload-url" id="url-input" style="width: 250px;" placeholder="http://example.com/image.png">
       <button onclick="show()">Add Image</button>
    <p id="image"></p>



<script>

var u = document.getElementById('url-input').value;

function show(){
document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = u;
}

</script>
```

What I want to do is enter a URL like:

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ50tL9UuaKby66enSL1s-5F6jVWmp5uzMQ1Rpx2yNV-was0pvR

and show it in the PARAGRAPH tag when I click the button. How can I accomplish this?
I am open to using JavaScript.

Comment: You could use an on-click event to listen to the mouse. But, this would require Javascript...are you wanting to use Javascript?

Comment: yes, I could use JavaScript.

Comment: the solution is trivial, please try solving it yourself first. and if you get stuck, then edit your question and post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have. that is why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work.

```
function onclick(){
    var input = document.getElementById('url-input');
    //the url from the input element
    var url = input.value;

    //create new img element
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src",url);

    //append img to p tag
    var paragraph = document.getElementById('image');
    paragraph.appendChild(img);
}
```